# 'ThemeProvider' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'

Tags: reactjs, themeprovider

I am trying to implement ThemeProvider but getting error
'ThemeProvider' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'
Here's the code

> ```
>  <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
>       <div className="card-box">
>         <Switch checked={darkState} onChange={handleThemeChange} />
>         <Card />
>       </div>
>     </ThemeProvider>
> ```

This is how I am Importing

> import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from
> "@material-ui/core/styles";

I have installed material-ui/styles using NPM but didn't resolve my problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Replacing ThemeProvider with MuiThemeProvider worked. But in Material-ui everywhere ThemeProvider is only used.

Comment: Try upgrading to 4.12.3! Thats where `createTheme` and `ThemeProvider` are released. Uninstall  material-ui/styles. Delete your node modules and try installing again.